# I get jQuery errors when i go previous page by clicking browser "back" button.

Tags: javascript, jquery

In mobile, when i go to my website the menu works well in all pages.
Once i click on browser 'back' button and go back to previous page i get the mobile menu not working anymore and see the following errors:

```
mediaelement-and-player.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
    at mediaelement-and-player.min.js:3
    at mediaelement-and-player.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ mediaelement-and-player.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ mediaelement-and-player.min.js:3
kontakt.html:883 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at kontakt.html:883
(anonymous) @ kontakt.html:883
kontakt.html:887 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at kontakt.html:887
(anonymous) @ kontakt.html:887
kontakt.html:912 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at kontakt.html:912
(anonymous) @ kontakt.html:912
```

Any one has any clue please?

Comment: Without any idea how the page should function normally it's hard to help, what should `undefined` be, and why isn't it set? Have you tried setting a breakpoint on that line of code to see why it hasn't been initialised. Maybe a snippet of code from your project may help.

Comment: Try clearing your cache and verifying that the page you're loading should have jQuery loaded.

Comment: Do you have any code handling a case when the back button is hit?

Comment: Is the back button trigger being used for a $.get instead of a redirect? This would make sense if the framework is changing the default behavior of the browser to load a view. That way it is returning HTML and not actually loading the resources needed. If this is the case, this is bad. You should not be loading scripts and other calls from a get request. Google Chrome is warning devs about this now and how it is detrimental to the end user.

Comment: I have not done any functional work with the browser back button. 
for example it says: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
for:
 $("#details_1017" ).bind("touchstart touchend touchmove click", function () { toggleModal('1017'); });
And many more...

Comment: When i come back clicking on browser back button it says: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
For
$(document).ready(function($) {.......